# Rails - Pass multiple text_fields as parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read everything I can on forms and such and they never seem to work the way I want them to. 
As a work around, I'm trying to pass a series of parameters to my controller via remote: true and javascript. I've got a solid foundation working.

I can't think of a proper way to explain this without getting too crazy, so I'll just explain what I am doing.

Goal-
 I have a FlashCard model going. The flash cards each have: Title, lines(7) and a body. The body is represented as the back of the card. The front of the card consists of the title and 7 lines. Each line can be written on individually and optionally centered. The card can be formatted as either read or write. Obviously read is a read-only and write gives you the ability to change whether or not each line is centered, and change/add the text on the title, each line, and the body.

Now. I probably chose a bad way to do this, but it's how I chose to do it. I have an affinity towards arrays so I tend to use those when in doubt. 
My flash card model has title:string, line:string as array, and body:text.
The line is formatted as follows: [["",0],["",0],["",0],["",0],["",0],["",0],["",0]]
The strings are the string on each line and the 0's can be either 0 or 1, as false and true- representing whether or not the text on that line is centered.

As far as displaying all of this, I have it working just fine. However- actually saving the data is proving to be a problem. Forms are not working out for me because of the line array/attribute. I don't mind doing the logic myself without the form, but I need a way to pass the data from the text_fields to the controller to save them.

Hopefully that makes sense. If not- I will happily add in the code I have used to get to where I am and more specifically show where I am having problems.

Optimally, I would like to simply pass the strings from multiple text_fields as separate parameters to the controller. If necessary to go back and entirely redo the model, I will do so if it will work as long as I can get the same functionality.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How difficult would it be to refactor your app so that `Line` is its own class and it `belongs_to` a `FlashCard`?  This would be easier to set up as a form i.e. you could use Rails' default functionality for associations in forms.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be too hard. 
I remember considering doing that in the beginning and went with this way for some reason... I can't think of why though. I may just go back and do that if it isn't too big of a pain, which I don't think it should be.

Comment: You can do it as you've written it but it will take a bit more manual intervention. For each `line` in your form, you'll need to have the names of the input field/checkbox (for centring) as `line1[body]` and `line1[centre]`. In your controller, for each line, you can access `params[:lineX]` and then convert to array. It's messy though.

Comment: That's the part I was having trouble with- actually passing the lines as parameters. Passing the info from a single line is easy, but how do I tell one button to pass the parameters of every line, title, and body?

Comment: A submit button will pass the value of every input in a form. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robinjfisher/8f4a1d8f69d337bff3ac). The controller will be a bit messy although you might be able to refactor if you name the line parameters in a certain way. I still think, if you can, having a distinct `Line` model and then using [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) is the way to go.